# pagination does not show total page count

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using jquery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin for sorting and pagination of table (tablesorter.pager.js).

i have so many list pages and it works fine.
in one page i am dynamically loading page based on the filter (basically on clicking a button part of page loads with table)

on loading that table pagination shows total page (1/1) even there is more than 1 page .
but on sorting any column it shows page count correctly like (1/8) i.e only on loading it does not show page count correctly.

all other functionality works fine.

jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  if(0 < $("#listTable tbody tr").length){ 
      $("table") 
        .tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0]],widthFixed: true }) 
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
    }
```

});

I have tried setting default sorting but it does not work.
what will be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

changed some thing like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(0 < $("#listTable tbody tr").length){ 
      $("#listTable") 
      .tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0]],widthFixed: true }) 
     .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
}
```

and its working!